# Why use libtool to build libraries?

Tags: gcc, libtool

```
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g   -o pcretest pcretest.o libpcreposix.la
libtool: link: gcc -g -o .libs/pcretest pcretest.o  ./.libs/libpcreposix.so /root/test/pcre-8.12/.libs/libpcre.so
```

It seems using libtool only makes it more complex,why not just stick to gcc ?

Answer (score 4):

Because you might not be using gcc on another platform.  The whole purpose of libtool is to be able to link on a multitude of platforms without needing to know the details of how each linker works and operating system environment works.

Comment: Not only that, but some systems require different flags for building a static vs a shared library. `libtool` abstracts that away behind a consistent interface using `.lo`/`.la` files.